# sql to xml and encoding issues

Tags: mysql, xml, encoding, utf-8

I have a SQL database and it's encoding type is utf8.
On the webpage that shows and inserts the data to the SQL database the encoding is windows-1255.
Everything works great, all the letters are shown correctly.
The problem is when I save the sql database as an XML file and try to view it or when I enter manually to the database I just see strange letters, for instance: øðå.

Is there any way to repair it?
tried changing the XML encoding to windows-1255 and to utf8, nothing.

Comment: mysql3 MySQL client version: 5.0.67, phpmyadmin 2.11, I hope this is what you meant